# Среда выдает ошибку " 'M' does not name a type" в двух последних строках. Как исправить?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char M [20][10];
int x=20/2;
int y=10/2;
int fruitX = rand() % 20;
int fruitY = rand() % 10;
int k=0;
bool gameOver = false;
char direction = 0;
M[x][y] = '0';
M[fruitX][fruitY]= 'F';
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете на С++, что следует из единственного тега к вопросу, то уже должны были узнать, что каждая программа на этом языке обязана иметь **точку входа**, проще говоря - функцию `main()`

Попробуйте вот так (код обновлен по данным, полученным из комментария автора):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Объявление всех необходимых глобальных переменных
 * Эти переменные будут доступны из всех частей программы
 * по своему имени */
char M[20][10];
int x = 20 / 2; // Это константное выражение, компилятор может посчитать
int y = 10 / 2; // его на этапе сборки, поэтому им можно инициализировать переменные
int fruitX; // В области объявлений нельзя вычислить rand() % 20,
int fruitY; // поэтому инициализировать НЕконстантным выражением переменную нельзя
int k = 0;
bool gameOver = false;
char direction = 0;

/* Точка входа, эта функция выполняется после старта программы */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* Обратите внимание, что мы используем глобальную переменную
     * Если написать что-то вроде
     * int fruitX = rand() % 20;
     * то в этой области видимости мы закроем глобальную переменную
     * локальной переменной с тем же именем. Нам это не нужно */
    fruitX = rand() % 20;
    fruitY = rand() % 10;
    M[x][y] = '0';
    M[fruitX][fruitY] = 'F';
}
```

Ваша программа ничего не делает и ничего не выводит, но теперь хотя бы собирается (проверял на gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16))

Обучение С++ лучше вести по книгам, поэтапно, вдумчиво. Вариант "скопировал пример и что-то заработало" здесь чреват проблемами и пробелами в понимании. Язык серьезный, отнеситесь к нему с уважением ) Удачи

UPD: Дополнил код, добавил комментарии

Comment: дело в том, что все эти переменные нужно использовать в функциях, а использовать указатели  не очень хочется

Comment: Мы об этом должны были догадаться с помощью телепатии? Просто объявите (declaration) переменные вне функции, они станут глобальными, и используете на здоровье. Ваша изначальная проблема была в том, что вы пытались сделать присвоение (операцию реализации, implementation) вне функции. А вне функции можно только объявлять, декларировать, выполнять что-то - нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что весь Ваш "код" находится вне функций. А там переменные можно объявлять, а вот вычислять просто так выражения - уже нельзя. то есть, написать M[x][y] = '0'; нельзя. Это можно писать уже только внутри функции. Скорее всего кто то просто забыл написать `int main() {` перед `char M`. Ну и закрыть фигурную скобку в конце.